# Python script pulling information from Json but need to modify the key and value

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key

I'm writing a Python script to login to a server and collect the device

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "console": "telnet",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "R1",
            "ram": 512,
            "status": 0,
            "url": "telnet://127.0.0.1:32769",
            "uuid": "ab60e9de-2599-4b67-919a-b769fb6e270d"
        },
        "2": {
            "console": "telnet",
            "id": 2,
            "name": "R2",
            "ram": 512,
            "status": 0,
            "url": "telnet://127.0.0.1:32770",
            "uuid": "206323a6-000b-40bc-a765-9c7e7e5751ee"
        },
```

I need to collect just the name and url. Here is a copy of the Python script.

```
import json
address = '192.168.1.113'
instance = m11.Server(address)
instance.login('admin', 'password', '0')
users = instance.get_all_nodes()
payload = json.loads(users.content)
data = payload['data']

dict = {}
for item in data:
    dict[item] = payload['data'][item]['url']
print (dict)
```

Here is a copy of the output I'm receiving.

{'1': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32769', '2': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32770', '3': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32771', '4': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32772', '6': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32774', '5': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32773', '7': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32775', '8': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32776', '9': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32777', '10': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32778', '11': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32779', '12': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32780', '13': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32781', '14': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32782', '15': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32783', '16': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32784', '17': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32785', '18': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32786', '19': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32787', '20': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32788', '21': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32789', '22': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32790', '23': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32791', '24': 'telnet://192.168.1.113:32792'}
[Finished in 1.365s]

How do I modify the script to key on the name and keep the url as the value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)):

```
result = {v["name"]: v["url"] for v in payload["data"].values()}
print(result)
```

**Output** *(for the given sample data)*

```
{'R1': 'telnet://127.0.0.1:32769', 'R2': 'telnet://127.0.0.1:32770'}
```

Or just change the for loop in your script to:

```
result = {}
for v in payload["data"].values():
    result[v["name"]] = v["url"]

print(result)
```

Also avoid using dict as a variable name as it shadows the built-in dict.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked I really appreciate it. I'll go study dictionary comprehension now.